# Using Presentation API / Google Cast to present a clock website

Tags: google-cast, presentation-api

I've been searching on this for a while. I've read up on the Moz and Google documentation for the presentation API, however, I am unable to cast the website when prompted because it says the TV is "available for specific video sites."

I've searched some more and found that you must pay $5 (which I would be willing to do if I knew it would work) to register a receiver. After searching Stack Overflow for google cast, it seems that nearly everything has been disabled. I've tried putting in an empty video element but it still does not work.

I also see that a receiver is a different html page, but also that it would be uploaded as an Android app (?). I know that the presentation API is a generic presentation API, while Google Cast is specifically for Chromecast it seems. I can't seem to get anything working on any device or method to cast to the TV. I can cast YouTube but that's it. I'm wondering how I would go about getting my clock website castable to a TV. Thanks in advance.

[Casting a tab](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332) help article doesn't seem to work for me either.

Here are relevant screenshots:

[image: cast tab screenshot]

[image: cast desktop screenshot]

---

[Mozilla Docs Presentation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Presentation_API#starting_a_new_presentation)

[Chrome Sample Presentation API](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/presentation-api/)

[Google Web Docs Presentation API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/04/present-web-pages-to-secondary-attached-displays#samples_and_demos)

[Google Cast Docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to cast to a Samsung TV. Samsung TVs however don't really support support the real deal Chromecast protocol where you can mirror screens. I think what Chrome does here is when you are watching on supported site like Youtube or Twitch - it will remotely launch the right "App" on your Samsung TV and send over the link. It is however not possible to mirror ANY website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I believe the Samsung TV does have Chromecast plugged in, but I guess you're saying it's using the Samsung thing instead. I'm wondering if with Chromecast if I'd be able to mirror the website. I see you say it's "not possible to mirror any website" so does this mean it's impossible?